# SUM of array with the same variable php

Tags: php

I have a dynamic variable a with different values

```
$a = (1,2,3,4,5);  
$a = (2,3,4,5,6);
```

I want a result that will sum each index of each array

```
$a = (3,5,7,9,11);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){  
   $a = explode(',',$row['array']); //array with same variable name
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a proper example that can be replicated? The example you've given is both a syntax error and also reassigning the same variable to two different values - hard to know what you mean

Comment: welcome , SO is not a platform to write code , show what you have tried so far?

Comment: i edited my code

Comment: There's no magic function for this, you'll need to write a loop and do the addition manually. Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried everything i could, but im sucks with looping statement :(

Comment: You can use array_map () function for getting the sum

Comment: i've tried array_map(), but i cant get it to work

Comment: Please post enough code to repeat your problem. You said that you've edited your code, but [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995045/sum-of-array-with-the-same-variable-php#comment87006425_49995045) is still totally true

Comment: they have the same variable name because they're inside a column, i cant provide more code because that's all i know, but i just wonder if it is possible to get sum using any looping ? :(, sorry im bad with english

Comment: @Yoshi thanks for the )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$a = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){  
    $a = array_map(function ($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }, $a,  explode(',',$row['array']));
}
print_r($a);
```

Assuming your code returns rows of

```
$row['array'] = '1,2,3,4,5';  
$row['array'] = '2,3,4,5,6';
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 11
)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below code will help you out

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,4,5);  
$b = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,3);
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
$temp = $a[$k]+$b[$k];
$c[] = $temp;
}
print_r($c);
```